# selectInput not working when variables are selected

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hopefully just a quick question, I have added in a `selectInput` function into my code and linked this to the server, however whenever I change the "year" within the app the scatterplot doesn't change the plots based on the year.

Am I missing some code?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
pigs <- read.csv("pigs_data.csv")
# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
# Application title
titlePanel("Pig Breeding"),
sidebarLayout( 
sidebarPanel(
  #Allows user to choose a year which changes the distribution of plot points
selectInput(inputId = "year",
            label = "Choose a year:",
            choices = c(2016, 2017, 2018),
            selectize = FALSE
            )
),
# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
plotOutput("scatterplot")
)
)
)
# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
                    input$year
                    ggplot(pigs, 
                    aes(x = sow_count, y = species, col = species)) + 
                    geom_point() +
                    facet_grid(. ~year)
})
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - before trying the `observeEvent` solution:

Depending on what exactly you want to plot it could be becaose of `facet_grid(. ~year)` and not `facet_grid(. ~input$year)`.

If `facet_grid(. ~input$year)` is not what you are looking for, then ...
You can try the `observeEvent` from the shiny package:

```
observeEvent(input$year, {
    output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
      input$year
      ggplot(pigs, 
             aes(x = sow_count, y = species, col = species)) + 
        geom_point() +
        facet_grid(. ~year)
    })
})
```

Basically whenever the object `input$year` changes, you render a new plot.

Your example will look like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
pigs <- read.csv("pigs_data.csv")
# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Pig Breeding"),
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      #Allows user to choose a year which changes the distribution of plot points
      selectInput(inputId = "year",
                  label = "Choose a year:",
                  choices = c(2016, 2017, 2018),
                  selectize = FALSE
      )
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatterplot")
    )
  )
)
# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$year, {
    output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
      input$year
      ggplot(pigs, 
             aes(x = sow_count, y = species, col = species)) + 
        geom_point() +
        facet_grid(. ~year)
    })
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to update your table **pigs** if it contains the variable ***year*** like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
                    input$year
                    ggplot(pigs %>% filter(year %in% input$year), 
                    aes(x = sow_count, y = species, col = species)) + 
                    geom_point() +
                    facet_grid(. ~year)
})
}
```

Hope this help.